# How can I get my Azure Node.js Web App to start

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

I know this is a common issue, but I'm stumped; details

- Basic Node.js WebApp, accessing SQL Server
- Currently, just returns the contents of a small table
- Based on something like: https://medium.com/voobans-tech-stories/how-to-quickly-create-a-simple-rest-api-for-sql-server-database-7ddb595f751a
- Developed and deployed using Visual Studio
- Works fine in Visual Studio i.e. a localhost deployment
- But won't start in Azure i.e. attempting to browse to WebApp's address; returns "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.", or 502 / 503 errors

I've tried various blogs, so far to no avail. I know there can be many reasons for this; all I'm looking for is a checklist of most likely / common problems. Any help appreciated

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: can you supply some codes?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when the application returns 500 Errors when it starts, there could be a few reasons:

1. Node.exe is not present at the correct location. Check
   nodeProcessCommandLine setting.
2. Main script file is not present at the correct location. Check
   web.config and make sure the name of the main script file in the
   handlers section matches the main script file.
3. Web.config configuration is not correct – check the settings
   names/values.
4. Cold Start – Your application is taking too long to start. If your
   application takes longer than (maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry *
   namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay) / 1000 seconds, iisnode returns a 500
   error. Increase the values of these settings to match your
   application start time to prevent iisnode from timing out and
   returning the 500 error.

When a working Node.js app behaves differently in App Service or has errors, you try the following as a sequence/check-list to isolate the problem.

- [Access the log stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-nodejs#access-diagnostic-logs).

Test the app locally in production mode. App Service runs your Node.js apps in production mode, so you need to make sure that your project works as expected in production mode
locally. For example:

- Depending on your package.json, different packages may be installed for production mode (dependencies vs.devDependencies).
- Certain web frameworks may deploy static files differently in production mode.
- Certain web frameworks may usecustom startup scripts when running in
  production mode.

Run your app in App Service in development mode. For example, in MEAN.js, you can
set your app to development mode in runtime by setting the NODE_ENV app setting.

Kindly checkout these documentations which highlights these steps/checklist:

[Best practices and troubleshooting guide for node applications on Azure App Service Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide#my-node-application-does-not-start)

[Node.js App deployment and troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-nodejs#troubleshooting)